# RenderAction cannot be used with type arguments (MVC 5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC. A project that I am attempting to upgrade from MVC 3 -> MVC 5 has most of its calls to `RenderAction`, `ActionLink` etc in a format that is different to what I've seen in tutorials for MVC.

Specifically an invocation of a method looks like this:

```
@{Html.RenderAction<MyControllerHere>(c => c.MyAwesomeMethod());}
```

Razor is reporting the error:

> The non generic method ...RenderAction(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelperString) cannot be used with type arguments.

Is this syntax still supported in MVC?

If so, what is the type argument referred to in the error? 
If not how does this translate to current syntax?

Comment: Keep in mind that you can write your own `HtmlHelper` extension methods to provide this functionality again. You can probably find example code on the Internet, or you could look at the source code used in MVC when it contained the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll address your questions individually:

#### Is the syntax still supported?

Not as far as I know. I couldn't find an official source to confirm this, but as far as I understand, it was temporarily available as part of MVC Futures.

#### What is the type argument referred to in the error?

The C# type argument passed to the call to `RenderAction`. In your example, it is `MyControllerHere`.

#### How does this translate to current syntax?

Assuming your controller follows the default convention of having the `Controller` name suffix, such as `MyController`:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("MyAwesomeMethod", "My");}
```

I haven't tested this, but I believe it's mostly right.